# PHP soapclient request with long value in Transaction Express

Tags: php, soap

Am using php5.6 win:8.1

Unable to make wallet sale through SOAP client.

My request array like

```
([reqAmt] => 025000
[recurMan] => Array  ([id] => 1537444446788162467
 )
[merc] => Array(
    [id] => 1223234234
    [regKey] => adsds23234343
    [inType] => 1
    [prodType] => 5
)
[tranCode] => 0
)
```

But last sent request printed

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="http://postilion/realtime/merchantframework/xsd/v1/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:SendTranRequest>
<ns1:merc>
<ns1:id>1223234234</ns1:id>
<ns1:regKey>adsds23234343</ns1:regKey>
<ns1:inType>1</ns1:inType>
<ns1:prodType>5</ns1:prodType>
</ns1:merc>
<ns1:tranCode>0</ns1:tranCode>
<ns1:reqAmt>025000</ns1:reqAmt>
<ns1:recurMan>
<ns1:id>2147483647</ns1:id>
</ns1:recurMan>
</ns1:SendTranRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If I convert to float before sent request then wallet id changed
from  (send)1537444446788162467   (soap)1537444446788162560

How to resolve it ?

Comment: What is the WSDL expecting, an int or a float? Also, are you using 32 or 64 bit PHP?

Comment: WSDL expecting long
Using 64 bit PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a guess here, but if the SOAP endpoint does actually expect an Int and not a Float, then I'm guessing you are running a 32 Bit version of PHP.

The 32 bit version of PHP has a `PHP_INT_MAX` value of `2147483647`.

The 32 bit version of PHP has a `PHP_INT_MAX` value of `9223372036854775807`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

If that's the case, I hope your Windows is 64 bit! Update your PHP installation.

> UPDATE.

Ok you commented that 'WSDL expecting long Using 64 bit PHP'. Therefore it will reject an integer! So just make it a float!

```
 'id' => (float) 7777778541
```

Comment: (float)1537444446788162467 converted to 1.5374444467882E+18
and sent 1537444446788162560 in soab request
last 3 digit was changed

Comment: maybe just do the number + 0.0 ?

Comment: No affect.
1537444446788162467+0.0 also return 1.5374444467882E+18 
mean 1537444446788162560